# Getting a custom Bézier curve function to work

Tags: plotting, splines

In general, the $nth$-degree *Bézier* curve is defined as:
$$\vec{C}(u)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} B_{i,n}(u) \vec{P_i} \qquad 0\leq u\leq1$$

where $B_{i,n}(u)$ is the classical *Bernstein* polynomial,
$$B_{i,n}(u)=\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}u^i(1-u)^{n-i}$$

$\vec{P_i}$ is the *control point*.

I have written a function to plot these curves:

**Trial 1**

```
bezierPlot1[n_, pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]]:=
 ParametricPlot[
  Total@Table[
   BernsteinBasis[n, i, u] # & /@ pts, {i, 0, n}], {u, 0, 1}]

pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}};
bezierPlot1[3,pts]
```

> It failed; that is, no graphics appeared.

**Trial 2**

I replaced the *built-in* function `BernsteinBasis` with $\frac{n!}{i! (n - i)!} u^i(1 - u)^{n - i}$

```
 bezierPlot2[n_, pts : {{_, _} ..}, u_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
  ParametricPlot[
   Total@Table[
     n!/(i! (n - i)!) u^i (1 - u)^(n - i) # & /@ pts, {i, 0, n}] /. 
    u -> x, {x, 0, 1}]

 bezierPlot2[3, pts, u]
```

> It failed

Lastly, I know that *Mathematica* has the *built-in* function `BezierCurve`:

```
Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

> [image: Bézier curve]

So my question is, how do I make my `bezierPlot` work normally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
f[n_, j_, u_] := PiecewiseExpand[BernsteinBasis[n, j, u]]
cv[pt_, n_, u_] := (f[n, #, u] & /@ Range[0, n]).pt
```

Test:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}};
ParametricPlot[cv[pts, Length@pts - 1, v], {v, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 6}]
```

[image]

Or

```
DynamicModule[{p = {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], Dynamic@
   ParametricPlot[cv[p, Length@p - 1, v], {v, 0, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p], Green, Line[p]}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 6}], Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

To plot:

```
bezplot[pt_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
 ParametricPlot[cv[pt, Length@pt - 1, x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pt], Green, Line[pt]}, opts]
```

So,

```
bezplot[pts, PlotRange -> {0, 6}]
```

yields the first figure

Comment: +1, Thanks very much. BTW, could you tell me why does my method cannot work. I'd like know which reason lead to the failture and I will avoid this mistake next time. :-)

Comment: @Tangshutao apologies for delay in replying (timezone issue)...you seem to have solved yourself with your answer

Comment: Dear ubpdqn, That's all right,it's my pleasure to learn from your solution.:-)

Comment: Hi, @ubpdqn, today, I discovered a difference between `BezierCurve` and our functions `bezplot & bezierPlot`,     `pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}, {6, 0}};
Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]` seemed give the wrong result in V8 and V9.Do you think is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

I believe ...

```
bezierPlot1[n_, pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
 ParametricPlot[ Sum[BernsteinBasis[n - 1, i, u] pts[[i + 1]], {i, 0, n - 1}], {u, 0, 1}, opts]

pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 2}};
bezierPlot1[4, pts,  Epilog -> {Green, Line@pts, PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@pts}, 
                                PlotRange -> Evaluate[{Min @@ #, Max @@ #} & /@ Transpose@pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Dear belisarius, If I omit the `n`, namely, `bezierPlot[pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Module[{n = Length@opts},
  Show[
   {ParametricPlot[
     Sum[
      BernsteinBasis[n - 1, i, u] pts[[i + 1]], {i, 0, n - 1}], {u, 0,
       1}],
    Graphics[{Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]}, opts]
  ]`  it will lost the Besier curve, Could you tell me? I alway confused when I encounter the condition.Thanks

Comment: `n = Length@pts` NOTE: `pts` not `opts`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Ok, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Review**

`Table[BernsteinBasis[n, i, u] # & /@ pts, {i, 0, n}]` was the main problem.

**Revising**

I use the `MapIndexed` to fill in the second argument in `BernsteinBasis[n, i, u]`

```
 bezierPlot[n_, pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
  ParametricPlot[
   Total@MapIndexed[
    BernsteinBasis[n, First@#2 - 1, u] #1 &, pts], {u, 0, 1}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, opts]
```

**Test**

```
pts={{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}};
bezierPlot[3, pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 6}}]
```

> [image]

## Edit

```
bezierPlotSuper[n_, pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 ParametricPlot[
  Total@MapIndexed[
   BernsteinBasis[n, First@#2 - 1, u] #1 &, pts], {u, 0, 1},
    Epilog -> Join[
      Text @@@ (Thread@{Table[Style[Subscript["P", i], 14], {i, 0, n}],
        # + {.4, .2} & /@ pts}), 
      {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}], opts]
```

**Test**

```
bezierPlotSuper[3, {{2, 0}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1,11}}]
```

> [image]